# Untangle me. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I am a kind of tangle.

But I don't look like noodles.

I may look like a packet of noodle.

I do not look like an entangled headphone.

But I look more like a smartphone.

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are a

> Rectangle

Because

> A packet of noodles and a smartphone are both shaped like rectangles, but noodles and earphones are shaped more like lines

Comment: Wow that is superfast

Comment: This is my intended answer. I still have to wait 8 minutes to accept it :(

Answer (score 1):

> Are you space-time continuum (according to String theory) where strings interact in a way and they dance about in the whole space and they are responsible for what we called particles. Of course strings look like noodles pack because they are everywhere "packed" and you can't see them apart to exactly say them as noodles. They just always vibrate. Like a smartphone you can see a visible sheet where you can interact so much as the ground you stand (you interact with smartphone using fingers but here with your leg mostly). Generally speaking strings can form knots [See here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9704084v3.pdf) and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9610193). So, you interact with the strings everyday like a visible screen but you can't see them just as you can't see directly the internal parts of a smartphone.

Comment: I dont know string theory though. Thank you for making an attempt.

Comment: Oh I thought you meant 'knots' through the word tangle. I get it now.

Comment: Although my intended answer was a tiny wordplay about rectangle, you gifted us a lesson about string theory <3. Perhaps I would not understand any of cited papers still thanks it will help a lot of people